# bootstrap input, textarea float-label css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, label

I am using **Bootstrap Float-label** functionality. Ref => https://github.com/tonystar/float-label-css

Note : I have made some changes as per my requirement.

**Problems :**

**1)** When we click on any input, float-label is working fine. But in float-label background bootstrap's form input border is visible.

[image]

**2)** When validation occurs, next input's float-label disrupts like float-label goes above the input field. I am using `<span id="error_*****" class="error"></span>` outside of `<span class="has-float-label">`

[image]

**3)** Appearance in different browsers as below.
In IE & Edge, float-label by-default applied. Is it OK or any solutions for IE, Edge ?

[image]

**Other Information for my case :**

> Windows 10 64-bit
>   Firefox (Version 72.0.1)
>   Chrome (Version 79.0.3945.117)
>   Opera (Version 65.0.3467.78)
>   MS-Edge (Version 44.18362.449.0)
>   MS-IE (Version 11.535.18362.0)
>   For snippet => Bootstrap 4.4.1 is used.

```js
function trim(stringToTrim) {
 return stringToTrim.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#btn_contactus").click(function () {
  //alert("hi");return false;
  if ( trim($("#firstname").val()) == '' )
  {
   $("#error_firstname").html('Please enter First Name');
   $("#error_firstname").show();
   $("#firstname").val('').focus();
   return false;
  }
  else
  {
   $("#error_firstname").hide();
  }
  if ( trim($("#lastname").val()) == '' )
  {
   $("#error_lastname").html('Please enter Last Name');
   $("#error_lastname").show();
   $("#lastname").val('').focus();
   return false;
  }
  else
  {
   $("#error_lastname").hide();
  }
  var emailfilter  = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  if ( !emailfilter.test(trim($("#emailid").val())) )
  {
   $("#error_emailid").html('Please enter Valid Email ID');
   $("#error_emailid").show();
   $("#emailid").focus();
   return false;
  }
  else
  {
   $("#error_emailid").hide();
  }
  if ( trim($("#phone").val()) == '' )
  {
   $("#error_phone").html('Please enter only 10 digits, not starting with 0. Valid Format : xxx-xxx-xxxx');
   $("#error_phone").show();
   $("#phone").val('').focus();
   return false;
  }
  else
  {
   var value = trim($("#phone").val());
   var phonefilter = /^(?!(0))\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}$/;
   if ( !phonefilter.test(value) )
   {
    $("#error_phone").html('Please enter only 10 digits, not starting with 0. Valid Format : xxx-xxx-xxxx');
    $("#error_phone").show();
    $("#phone").focus();
    return false;

   }
   else
   {
    $("#error_phone").hide();
   }
  }
  if ( trim($("#comments").val()) == '' )
  {
   $("#error_comments").html('Please enter Comments/Inquiry');
   $("#error_comments").show();
   $("#comments").val('').focus();
   return false;
  }
  else
  {
   $("#error_comments").hide();
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.instruction {
  font-size:13px;
  font-weight:600;
  color:green;
}
.required {
  font-size:13px;
  color:#D00;
}
.error {
  font-size:14px;
 font-weight: 600;
 color:#D00;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 background-color:transparent;
}
.has-float-label{
 display:block;
 position:relative
}
.has-float-label label,.has-float-label>span{
 position:absolute;
 cursor:text;
 font-size:75%;
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition:all .2s;
 transition:all .2s;
 top:-.5em;
 left:.75rem;
 z-index:3;
 line-height:1;
 padding:0 1px
}
.has-float-label label::after,.has-float-label>span::after{
 content:" ";
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 background:#fff;
 height:2px;
 top:50%;
 left:-.2em;
 right:-.2em;
 z-index:-1
}
.has-float-label .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder{
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition:all .2s;
 transition:all .2s
}
.has-float-label .form-control::-moz-placeholder{
 opacity:1;
 transition:all .2s
}
.has-float-label .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder{
 opacity:1;
 transition:all .2s
}
.has-float-label .form-control::placeholder{
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition:all .2s;
 transition:all .2s
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::-webkit-input-placeholder{
 opacity:0
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::-moz-placeholder{
 opacity:0
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus):-ms-input-placeholder{
 opacity:0
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::placeholder{
 opacity:0
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)+*{
 font-size:100%;
 color: #6c757d;
 opacity: 1;
 top:.3em
}
.input-group .has-float-label{
 -webkit-box-flex:1;
 -webkit-flex-grow:1;
 -ms-flex-positive:1;
 flex-grow:1;
 margin-bottom:0;
 display:-webkit-box;
 display:-webkit-flex;
 display:-ms-flexbox;
 display:flex;
 -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
 -webkit-box-direction:normal;
 -webkit-flex-direction:column;
 -ms-flex-direction:column;
 flex-direction:column;
 -webkit-box-pack:center;
 -webkit-justify-content:center;
 -ms-flex-pack:center;
 justify-content:center
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus) + * {
 margin-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
        <h4 class="card-title">Contact Us</h4>
        <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group input-group col-md-6">
                    <span id="error_firstname" class="error"></span>
                    <span class="has-float-label">
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required="required">
                        <label for="firstname">First Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group col-md-6">
                    <span id="error_lastname" class="error"></span>
                    <span class="has-float-label">
                        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required="required">
                        <label for="lastname">Last Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group input-group col-md-6">
                    <span id="error_emailid" class="error"></span>
                    <span class="has-float-label">
                        <input type="email" name="emailid" value="" class="form-control" id="emailid" placeholder="Email ID" required="required">
                        <label for="emailid">Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group col-md-6">
                    <span id="error_phone" class="error"></span>
                    <span class="has-float-label">
                        <input type="text" name="phone" value="" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required="required" pattern="^(?!(0))\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}$">
                        <label for="phone">Phone Number <span class="required">*</span> <span class="instruction">Format : xxx-xxx-xxxx</span></label>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group input-group">
                <span class="has-float-label">
                    <input type="text" name="companyname" value="" class="form-control" id="companyname" placeholder="Company Name (Optional)">
                    <label for="companyname">Company Name <span class="text-muted">(Optional)</span></label>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group input-group">
                <span id="error_comments" class="error"></span>
                <span class="has-float-label">
                    <textarea name="comments" cols="50" rows="5" class="form-control" id="comments" placeholder="Comments/Inquiry" required="required"></textarea>
                    <label for="comments">Comments/Inquiry <span class="required">*</span></label>
                </span>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="btn_contactus" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_contactus" title="Submit">
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1:**  Set `background-color` of float label

**Solution 2:**  Removed `input-group` of place error below floating label(Its good to give message below input field not above)

**Solution 3:**  Please see this link may be this would help you [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48679715/floating-label-with-css-not-working-in-edge-internet-explorer)

```js
function trim(stringToTrim) {
 return stringToTrim.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#btn_contactus").click(function () {
  //alert("hi");return false;
  if ( trim($("#firstname").val()) == '' )
  {
   $("#error_firstname").html('Please enter First Name');
   $("#error_firstname").show();
   $("#firstname").val('').focus();
   return false;
  }
  else
  {
   $("#error_firstname").hide();
  }
  if ( trim($("#lastname").val()) == '' )
  {
   $("#error_lastname").html('Please enter Last Name');
   $("#error_lastname").show();
   $("#lastname").val('').focus();
   return false;
  }
  else
  {
   $("#error_lastname").hide();
  }
  var emailfilter  = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  if ( !emailfilter.test(trim($("#emailid").val())) )
  {
   $("#error_emailid").html('Please enter Valid Email ID');
   $("#error_emailid").show();
   $("#emailid").focus();
   return false;
  }
  else
  {
   $("#error_emailid").hide();
  }
  if ( trim($("#phone").val()) == '' )
  {
   $("#error_phone").html('Please enter only 10 digits, not starting with 0. Valid Format : xxx-xxx-xxxx');
   $("#error_phone").show();
   $("#phone").val('').focus();
   return false;
  }
  else
  {
   var value = trim($("#phone").val());
   var phonefilter = /^(?!(0))\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}$/;
   if ( !phonefilter.test(value) )
   {
    $("#error_phone").html('Please enter only 10 digits, not starting with 0. Valid Format : xxx-xxx-xxxx');
    $("#error_phone").show();
    $("#phone").focus();
    return false;

   }
   else
   {
    $("#error_phone").hide();
   }
  }
  if ( trim($("#comments").val()) == '' )
  {
   $("#error_comments").html('Please enter Comments/Inquiry');
   $("#error_comments").show();
   $("#comments").val('').focus();
   return false;
  }
  else
  {
   $("#error_comments").hide();
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.instruction {
  font-size:13px;
  font-weight:600;
  color:green;
}
.required {
  font-size:13px;
  color:#D00;
}
.error {
  font-size:11px;
 font-weight: 600;
 color:#D00;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 background-color:transparent;
}
.has-float-label{
 display:block;
 position:relative
}
.has-float-label label,.has-float-label>span{
 position:absolute;
 cursor:text;
 font-size:75%;
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition:all .2s;
 transition:all .2s;
 top:-.5em;
 left:.75rem;
 z-index:3;
 line-height:1;
 padding:0 2px;  
 background:#fff;
}
.has-float-label label::after,.has-float-label>span::after{
 content:" ";
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 background:#fff;
 height:2px;
 top:50%;
 left:-.2em;
 right:-.2em;
 z-index:-1
}
.has-float-label .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder{
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition:all .2s;
 transition:all .2s
}
.has-float-label .form-control::-moz-placeholder{
 opacity:1;
 transition:all .2s
}
.has-float-label .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder{
 opacity:1;
 transition:all .2s
}
.has-float-label .form-control::placeholder{
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition:all .2s;
 transition:all .2s
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::-webkit-input-placeholder{
 opacity:0
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::-moz-placeholder{
 opacity:0
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus):-ms-input-placeholder{
 opacity:0
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::placeholder{
 opacity:0
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)+*{
 font-size:100%;
 color: #6c757d;
 opacity: 1;
 top:.3em
}
.input-group .has-float-label{
 -webkit-box-flex:1;
 -webkit-flex-grow:1;
 -ms-flex-positive:1;
 flex-grow:1;
 margin-bottom:0;
 display:-webkit-box;
 display:-webkit-flex;
 display:-ms-flexbox;
 display:flex;
 -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
 -webkit-box-direction:normal;
 -webkit-flex-direction:column;
 -ms-flex-direction:column;
 flex-direction:column;
 -webkit-box-pack:center;
 -webkit-justify-content:center;
 -ms-flex-pack:center;
 justify-content:center
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus) + * {
 margin-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
        <h4 class="card-title">Contact Us</h4>
        <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                   
                    <span class="has-float-label">
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required="required">
                        <label for="firstname">First Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    </span>
                     <span id="error_firstname" class="error"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    
                    <span class="has-float-label">
                        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required="required">
                        <label for="lastname">Last Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    </span>
                    <span id="error_lastname" class="error"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    
                    <span class="has-float-label">
                        <input type="email" name="emailid" value="" class="form-control" id="emailid" placeholder="Email ID" required="required">
                        <label for="emailid">Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    </span>
                    <span id="error_emailid" class="error"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <span class="has-float-label">
                        <input type="text" name="phone" value="" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required="required" pattern="^(?!(0))\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}$">
                        <label for="phone">Phone Number <span class="required">*</span> <span class="instruction">Format : xxx-xxx-xxxx</span></label>
                    </span>
                    <span id="error_phone" class="error"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <span class="has-float-label">
                    <input type="text" name="companyname" value="" class="form-control" id="companyname" placeholder="Company Name (Optional)">
                    <label for="companyname">Company Name <span class="text-muted">(Optional)</span></label>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                
                <span class="has-float-label">
                    <textarea name="comments" cols="50" rows="5" class="form-control" id="comments" placeholder="Comments/Inquiry" required="required"></textarea>
                    <label for="comments">Comments/Inquiry <span class="required">*</span></label>
                </span><span id="error_comments" class="error"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="btn_contactus" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_contactus" title="Submit">
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```