# CSS :focus is ignored in Edge and Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, focus, microsoft-edge

I am using the focus in CSS for our placeholders to jump up when i am clicking inside but Edge is completaly ignoring my css. Its working with every browser but i dont find any solution for Edge. Any ideas what can cause the problem?

"I looked similar articles here but none of them seems working on the actual Edge. I tried also with : instead of :: at the ms- line also not working."

```css
input {
    padding:10px;
    width:95%;
  }
 
 
 label {
    margin:10px 0;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
  }
    
  span {
    padding:10px;
    pointer-events: none;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    transition: 0.2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
    opacity:0.5;
  }

  
  
  input:focus ~ span, input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ span {
    opacity:1;
    transform:translateY(-100%) translateX(-10px);
    font-size:10px;
    padding:5px 10px;;
    
  }
  
  /* For IE Browsers*/
  
  input:focus ~ span, input:not(:-ms-input-placeholder) ~ span {
    opacity:1;
    transform:translateY(-100%) translateX(-10px);
    font-size:10px;
  }
```

```html
<label>
     <input type="password" name="E_password" value="" placeholder=" " />
     <span>Passwort*</span>
</label>
```

Comment: I suggest you also post your HTML code along with your CSS code. Only CSS code is not helpful as we don't know about your HTML. So we are also not able to make a test with it. I made a test with other CSS: focus example and it is working fine with IE and Edge browser.

Comment: I updated the code - here clearly visible that by Edge the span not trnasforming.

Comment: It is working the same for me in Edge and IE as it is in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to test your issue and I am able to see the issue in the MS Edge (EdgeHtml) browser. In the IE browser, your code works fine.

I tried to add some CSS code below to make it work with the MS Edge (EdgeHtml) browser.

```
/* For Edge Browser*/

  input:focus ~ span, input:invalid:not(:focus)::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    opacity:1;
    transform:translateY(-100%) translateX(-10px);
    font-size:10px;
  }
```

Modified code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
input {
    padding:10px;
    width:95%;
  }
 
 
 label {
    margin:20px 0;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
  }
    
  span {
    padding:10px;
    pointer-events: none;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    transition: 0.2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
    opacity:0.5;
  }

  
  
  input:focus ~ span, input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ span {
    opacity:1;
    transform:translateY(-100%) translateX(-10px);
    font-size:10px;
    padding:5px 10px;;
    
  }
  
  /* For IE Browsers*/
  
  input:focus ~ span, input:not(:-ms-input-placeholder) ~ span {
    opacity:1;
    transform:translateY(-100%) translateX(-10px);
    font-size:10px;
  }

/* For Edge Browser*/
  
  input:focus ~ span, input:invalid:not(:focus)::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    opacity:1;
    transform:translateY(-100%) translateX(-10px);
    font-size:10px;
  }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<label>
     <input type="password" name="E_password" value="" placeholder=" " />
     <span>Password<sup><font color="red" class="imp" >*</font></span>
</label>  
</body>
</html>
```

Output in MS Edge (EdgeHtml) browser:

[image]

Output in IE 11 browser:

[image]

Reference:

[Floating Label with Css not working in edge, internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48679715/floating-label-with-css-not-working-in-edge-internet-explorer)

Comment: Wow! Thank you i looked for the answer overall in lot of articles but i havent found anywhere! I really aprriciate it!